# How do I translate JSP tags to SQL

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, jsp

Right now I'm working on a web application (with absolutely limited java/oracle sql experience) and I'm desperate for help.

I'm trying to get the values from the value tag under the semester id from the jsp page:

```
<tr>
      <th><label for="semester">Semester:</label></th>
      <td><select id="semester" name="semester">
          <option value='1'>Spring 2007 (01/29/2007 to 05/17/2007)</option>
          <option value='2'>January Intersession 2007 (01/02/2007 to 01/25/2007)</option>
          <option value='3'>Fall 2006 (08/30/2006 to 12/13/2006)</option>
          <option value='4'>Summer ALL 2006 (06/01/2006 to 08/17/2006)</option>
          <option value='5'>Summer00 2006 (06/01/2006 to 08/17/2006)</option>
          <option value='6'>Summer02 2006 (07/10/2006 to 08/17/2006)</option>
          <option value='7'>Summer01 2006 (06/01/2006 to 07/06/2006)</option>

      </select></td>
    </tr>
```

and my sql (nestled in java page in another jsp page):

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *" + 
  "FROM CRS_SEC_SR, CRS_COMMENTS_SR, SEMESTER_SR "+
  "WHERE SEMESTER_ID = '+semester+'");
```

Right now the `WHERE SEMESTER_ID = '+semester+' ");` it reports back with no values. 
My question is: how do I get the semester value (the "1", "2", etc.) from the jsp page to the sql -- SEMESTER_ID = [INSERT JSP VALUE HERE]

I know this looks like a complete mess, but I'm just trying to find the quickest solution because I've been working on this for ages and it's due in a hours. Thank you so much for whatever help anybody can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the java side, but your SQL statement looks like it's missing some joins.

You're going to end up with each row in CRS_SEC_SR matching to every single row in CRS_COMMENTS_SR, and then all of those rows matching to every single row in DEPT_SR, etc... You'll end up with `N*O*P*Q` rows. Is that really what you wanted?

Also, I suspect that your issue is the `*` following `CRS_COMMENTS5`. Either that's a hangover from when you were testing with `select *` or you're trying to multiply two columns together but forgot to add in the second column. I suspect the former.

I think your sql statement should look something like:

```
select disc,
       crs_cd,
       crs_sec,
       meeting_days,
       start_time,
       stop_time,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       building,
       rm,
       instructor_lname,
       seats_avail,
       crs_comments1,
       crs_comments2,
       crs_comments3,
       crs_comments4,
       crs_comments5
from   crs_sec_sr
       inner join crs_comments_sr on (<some join condition(s)>)
       inner join dept_sr on (<some join condition(s)>)
       inner join cours_sr on (<some join condition(s)>)
where  semester_id = '%semester%'
```

You'll have to add in the join conditions (and amend the joins to left/right outer joins if appropriate).

Is `where  semester_id = '%semester%'` correct? Currently it looks like you're searching for a string that looks like: `%semester%`  I'm not sure if the %'s are meant to represent a variable replacement? If so, ideally you should be using a bind variable. IME, id's are normally numeric.

Comment: So I updated the changes i made in the sql statement, i took out a bulk of the tables (it still works without it) but my difficulty is the where statement. I'm not sure how to translate the jsp "semester" id and value to the sql SEMESTER_ID value in the database.

Comment: I can't help with that, sorry. Hopefully someone else will come along soon and be able to help you with the rest. Good luck!

Comment: You're missing too much code to be able to help you.  You write ' java page in another jsp page' and I have no idea what that means.  You need to show the code where you are retrieving the value of the semester input.  Print that out to verify you have the value you expect.  Also, your query is messed up as well, @Boneist has given you guidance there.

Comment: Looking more closely at your query, there's more wrong there. You need whitespace after the '*' or before the 'FROM.' Also, assuming semester is a string value and not an int, change your last line to this:  "WHERE SEMESTER_ID = '" + semester + "'");  You need to add double quotes after the first ' and before the second.

Comment: @ghenghy I know my code is a mess, but you actually helped a lot, thank you!